# Django - Alternative for FileSystemStorage in Production Environment

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, production-environment, file-system-storage

I am fairly new to django and I want to deploy my app. I have used FileSystemStorage to store my files temporarily in a Media folder and deleting them afterwards, in my django app however I've also read that it should not be used in a production environment. My code is essentially the same as the one shown in this
[article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-upload-files-with-filesystemstorage/).

Why can't I use FileSystemStorage in a production environment and what can I use instead in order to serve my purpose?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: it's not recommend to use the static settings to serve the file because they can see your file code from url path if it's on production. To serve file to user like the article said use nginx instead ot serve files `As mentioned earlier, this method should only be used to serve media in development and not in production. You might want to use something like nginx in production.`

Comment: @Kroustou It's in the website that I mentioned

Comment: @LinhNguyen Actually, I'm not storing the files for a long time. I'm only saving them for a while; after processing the files they get deleted afterward.

Comment: oh then FileSystemStorage is perfectly normal for this kind of thing, you just need to set a variable to a file path and delete it afterward

Comment: @LinhNguyen I'm not sure I know how to do it, can you show me how? thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah now see what you meant. Yest static files should be served from nginx, not django itself. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle user uploaded file then delete it afterward here is how i implemented it in a simple view:

```
def my_image(request, image_name):
    # user upload file
    folder_path = 'path_to_your_file_folder/'
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=folder_path, base_url=folder_path)    
    
    image_data = open(folder_path + image_name, "rb").read() #set file as variable
    fs.delete(folder_path + image_name)# delete the file from folder
    return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image")
```

This view will return the image 1 time